# Async Adsense script - MVC .Net Partial view- include script only once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, adsense

I use a partial view to display any adsense ad in my MVC4 .net web apps. When I changed it from the older script to the new async version, I read that the referenced script from google only needs to be included one time. Since I'm including the script inside a partial view which may be referenced several times in one page, I'd like to simply have the first inclusion of the partial include the reference to the script, but any additional inclusions to skip the script reference.

Is there a "best" way to do this from inside the partial?

Answer (score 1):

This works so far, maybe there's still a better method though?

```
@if(Context.Items["IncludedAdsenseScript"] == null){
    //include script here
    // ...
    //set the context item so further access will not include the script reference
    Context.Items["IncludedAdsenseScript"] = true; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if every partial shares the same script bundle, put it at the Layout page, or the parent page, given that you can acesses every script in the same window, document domain!

Comment: yes, but the partial im using can be toggled between using the old version and the new async. so I'd like to keep everything encapsulated in the partial view with the parent being ignorant of any changes

Answer (score 0):

Put the script in it's own partial view then include that once followed by the other partial views.